# How can I limit the number of fingerprint attempts before fallback to other login type?

Tags: security, fingerprint

I've got a Nexus 6P and would like to reduce the number of allowed failures before it blocks fingerprint as an allowed login mechanism - according to https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6285273 you need to use the alternative login mechanism "*When your fingerprint isn't recognized after a few tries*".

It could be nice to know how many "a few" is (and whether this is an adaptive number that for example may take into account how recently it was correctly unlocked), but the point is that it can go (as in my recent testing) at least to 4 failures and succeed on the 5th attempt. I would be entirely happy to force it to block fingerprint access after two failures, but I can't find this as a setting from a bit of quick poking around.

Answer (score 1):

> It could be nice to know how many "a few" is....

From Marshmallow Compatibility Definition Document (CDD) , quoted [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/10/19/google-lays-out-requirements-for-fingerprint-sensors-in-android-6-0/)

- MUST rate limit attempts for at least 30 seconds after **5 false trials** for fingerprint verification

> .... and whether this is an adaptive number that for example may take into account how recently it was correctly unlocked

- CCD is silent on this so one could safely assume **5 attempts** holds

> .... happy to force it to block fingerprint access after two failures, but I can't find this as a setting

There doesn't appear to be any setting to **increase or decrease number of attempts** (google search)

[LockScreen Tweakbox](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-lockscreen-tweakbox-various-t2843945) is said to increase the number of attempts to 20

Comment: Corrent document link is here -> https://source.android.com/compatibility/6.0/android-6.0-cdd#7_3_10_fingeprint