# Possible to quickly expire a fingerprint?

Tags: lock-screens, security, fingerprint

Let's say I wanted to quickly prevent my fingerprint from unlocking my phone; so that the next time the lock screen shows, a password is required. Is there a way to expire the fingerprint unlock session right away?

I tried searching but didn't find much quickly.

Edit: Thank you for posting the answer [How can I limit the number of fingerprint attempts before fallback to other login type?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/148560/131553). That is helpful information (in that it eliminates one potential answer). But, I don't really want to change the number of attempts. I want to make the phone temporarily not accept the fingerprint. I don't want it to forget the print, I don't (strictly speaking) want to change the number of allowed attempts. I want to tell the phone "Hey, next time you unlock, require the password".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I limit the number of fingerprint attempts before fallback to other login type?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148560/how-can-i-limit-the-number-of-fingerprint-attempts-before-fallback-to-other-logi)

Comment: Well, I don't strictly want to limit the # of attempts. I want to expire the session. I was just thinking that changing the # of allowed attempts was one mechanism to get there.

Comment: As pointed out in the other answer, it is time limited as per the documentation. I haven't heard of a way doing either - reducing time or attempts. That of course doesn't mean I am right

Comment: You may consider editing your question so that it doesn't get closed as duplicate. As it stands,  duplicate flag seems valid

Comment: Thanks beeshyams. The answer you dug up was helpful (but disappointing). I appreciate it. I edited the question (by deletion) to capture my real intent.