# How can I make my lockout time stack?

Tags: security, lock-screens, locked-out

If anyone has ever used an IPhone (Or tried to mess with someone else's - yes, I'm looking at you) you may be aware the the lockout timer scales with each fail after 5 attempts.

I want to do this on android, preferably Without root. anyone know how?

**Edit** On IPhone, after 5 failed passcode attempts, you are locked out for a minute. If you keep failing, it escalates (it will go up to 5 mins, then 15, then 60) I basically want to replicate that behaviour on android, where its 30 seconds lockout (and does not go up in time)

Answer (score 1):

This feature is *[rate limiting](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=y11NBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA276&lpg=PA276&dq=brute+force+attack+protection+nikolay+elenkov&source=bl&ots=nU-wBQvY2D&sig=3psil8m7uVx3Sb0I-GVyA0bX1mU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjomqf_sIvTAhWMtI8KHSXKBZ0Q6AEIIDAC)*
 and is done to prevent *Brute Force Attack*

This being a *core security feature* , it can be changed at OS level ( if at all ) and certainly would not be possible  without root

While I could not find reference to PIN / password rate limiting, you can see the Compatibility Definition Document 
(CSD ) mandating that for finger print recognition, specifying the number of attempts and duration. See 
[How can I limit the number of fingerprint attempts before fallback to other login type?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/148560/131553)

Comment: Alright, well, it's a step in the right direction, I guess :)